Add a dependency with exact semver constraint through npm CLI
Is it possible to add the specified semver range of the installed package from CLI rather than editing package.json manually?
The following command:
npm i --save-peer react@">= 18" svelte@"*"

results in changes in package.json:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "svelte": "^4.2.18"
  }

But the required result is to add the exact semver ranges, including a wildcard:
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">= 18",
    "svelte": "*"
  }

The resolved versions (18.3.1 and 4.2.18) should only be mentioned in package-lock.json, not package.json.

You can use --save-prefix for ~ or ^ and --save-exact for neither, but not for others I don't think.

This can be achieved with low-level pkg command:
npm pkg set peerDependencies.react=">= 18" peerDependencies.svelte="*" && npm i

Also this may work differently in other package managers, e.g. yarn add is known to be able to add a version as is.
